# Binary to decimal conversion question

Tags: subnet, networking

If Decimal 15 = Binary 00001111 can it also equal 01111 ? If not why? 
[sheet with conversion decimal-binary](https://ibb.co/7NL6pP4)

Comment: Sadly, homework questions are off topic here.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know where to ask it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a subnet mask, you have 4 octet. So one of this is `00001111` (your 15 decimal).

The upper zero pad your octet (you have 1 byte to fill).

Obviously if you consider only a part of your byte, for example 5 bits, the value is the same, so you can consider the same thing.